# Wilcard resourceBundle keys spring web flow

Tags: spring, message

I'm currently working on a fairly straightforward spring web flow application with tiles. We load our error messages from a resource bundle. I've been overwriting the typeMismatch errors as such.

*commandObj.fieldName.amount.typeMismatch=The field fieldname's amount is not a valid number.*

Alas I've come a cropper on one of the screens because it uses a list of DTO's so I'm getting back errors like

*typeMismatch on someCommand.listFieldName[1].dtoField.amount*

I can't start putting in

*commandObj.listFieldName[0].dtoField.amount.typeMismatch=The dtoField amount is invalid in the first object in the list in commandObj*

*commandObj.listFieldName[1].dtoField.amount.typeMismatch=The dtoField amount is invalid in the second object in the list in commandObj*
:
:
:

I was hoping that the framework had some way of wildcarding the error messages like

*commandObj.listFieldName[*].dtoField.amount.typeMismatch=The dtoField amount is invalid in the {1} object in the list in commandObj*

I'm hoping this has been encountered before.

Thanks,
Mark.

Comment: I'm using WebFlowMessageCodesResolver..

Comment: By taking the array index out of the key i.e. [1] or [0]

commandObj.listFieldName.dtoField.amount.typeMismatch=DtoField is invalid

it matches.
Alas if the error occurs in the same field multiple times then it gets printed out on  the screen multiple times.